# On the number of complete Boolean algebras

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, open-problems, boolean-algebras

In their 1972 paper [On the number of complete Boolean algebras](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02945048) Monk and Solovay showed that if $\lambda$ is an infinite cardinal, then there are $2^{2^\lambda}$ many  isomorphism types of
complete Boolean algebras of power $2^\lambda.$ On the other hand, by a result of Pierce, a complete
Boolean algebra of infinite power $\kappa$ exists iff $\kappa=\kappa^{\aleph_0}$.

In the above mentioned paper, the following is asked:

**Question.** Suppose $\kappa=\kappa^{\aleph_0}$, but it is not of the form $2^\lambda$ for any $\lambda$. Are there ${2^\kappa}$ many  isomorphism types of
complete Boolean algebras of power $\kappa?$

> What is known about the above question?

Comment: One could also naturally ask for lower bounds on the number of isomorphism types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that there are still $2^\kappa$ many isomorphism types of complete Boolean algebras of power $\kappa$.

This is proved by Shelah, see  [Building complicated index models and Boolean algebras](https://shelah.logic.at/files/230169/511.pdf), Conclusion 2.17.

Comment: Perhaps you could say something about the argument method?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The proof, as one might expect, is based on several earlier definitions and lemmas, so rather long. So I think it is easier to just look at the paper and the proof.